# How to count number of a certain element there are in an array?

Tags: python, arrays

How would you implement a function which counts the number of `True`s in an array if it occurs consecutively it counts as 1. A simple example would be the:

```
arr=[True,True,False,True,False,True,False,False]
```

would return a counter of 3 as there are 2 separate trues and the two True elements at the beginning count as 1 another example could be

```
arr2=[False,True,True,False,True,True,True,True]
```

which would give the counter as 2.

the code I have so far:

```
def counter1():
    for i in range(len(ar)):
        if ar[i]==False and ar[i+1]==True:
            counter+=1
    return counter
```

This doesn't work in some cases.

Is there any way to do this without importing any external libraries?

Comment: What are the cases where it doesn't work? Can you see any kind of pattern in them, or figure out *why* they're failing?

Comment: @asyl, if you found one of the answers helping, would you mind marking it as answered?  That will give us credit for helping you. Thank you

Comment: @Kamil already did

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) then count the keys for each group.

```
import itertools
arr=[True,True,False,True,False,True,False,False]
data = itertools.groupby(arr)
print(sum(k for k,g in data))
```

---

*keys* produced by the groupby:

```
In [27]: for key,group in data:
    ...:     print(key)
    ...:     
True
False
True
False
True
False
```

---

[bool is a subclass of int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) - Since you are counting True's you can feed the keys directly to `sum`.

Comment: @MattDMo - itertools is not an external library, it is built-in - part of the language.

Comment: I think OP meant without using any imports, but incorrectly phrased it

Comment: My bad then, I'll leave it up as an example of a bad answer. - I hate to assume I know what the OP's are thinking or what they might have meant especially when we repeatedly ask for [mre]'s - the example code might be just that.

Comment: itertools is acceptable i was mentioning external libraries such as numpy

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way for me and understable for the other person reading code would be:

```
def count_unique_true(arr):
    counter = 0
    store_last_bool = False
    for t in arr:
        if t and not store_last_bool:
            counter += 1
        store_last_bool = t
    return counter
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way without any extra imports:

```py
arr=[True,True,False,True,False,True,False,False]
ans = int(arr[0]==True)
for i in range(1, len(arr)):
    if arr[i] and not arr[i-1]:
        ans += 1
print(ans)
```

This works because a new group of Trues will only start if `arr[i] and not arr[i-1]` is valid

Answer (score 0):

using your idea of counting places where `False` changes to `True`, here's a solution.

1. it solves the edge case where the list starts with True, and so could miss 1
2. it uses no libaries or imports
3. its just one line, so works nice as a *code golf* example
4. uses cool tools to know such as unpacking and the `zip` function

```
x=[True,True,False,True,False,True,False,False]

sum([prev ==False and next==True for prev, next in zip([False] + x, x+[False])])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ar=[True,True,False,True,False,True,False,False]

def counter1():
  count = ar[0]
  prev  = ar[0]
  for i in range(len(ar)):
     if ar[i] and ar[i] != prev:
        count+=1
     prev = ar[i]
  print(count) # ==> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

see below

```
def true_counter(lst):
    cnt = 0
    for idx, flag in enumerate(lst):
        if idx < len(lst) - 1:
            if flag and not lst[idx + 1]:
                cnt += 1
    if lst[-1]:
        cnt += 1
    return cnt


print(true_counter([True, True, False, True, False, True, False, False]))
print(true_counter([False, True, True, False, True, True, True, True]))
```